# How to force python to point to child even parent call?

Tags: python, oop

Now I have

```
class A:
    def start(self):
       return True

class B(A):
    def start(self):
       return False
```

Now if I want to make all the `A()` calls point or redirect to `B` class
for example

```
s=A()
s.start()
```

It should return False as `A` is overridden with `B` to `return False`

Is that possible?

Okay Edit 
My case is in Django view which is called in 3rd party package URLs and I want to override and the package call my child which I override it, But I solved it by overriding the url itself, so I'm asking if it can be done as a pythonic way not in a django way.

Comment: It is technically possible. The question is why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, `A` isn't overriden by `B`, it is _subclassed_ by `B`. Thus, if you create an instance of `A`, it is totally independent from `B`.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to modify the behavior of the parent class? The reason for sub-classing is so that you can change the behavior of a parent class in a child class, not modify the parent class its self.

Comment: In other words: are you allowed to change `A`, or are you trying to monkey-patch code that calls it even though you cannot control the calling code?

Comment: what does "a pythonic way not in a django way" even mean?

Comment: I solved it by adding a new url to my project points to the new Child view ( Django way to solve) , Pythonic way to solve as like what I asked about if it exists or not :)

Comment: Are you familiar with _monkeypatching_, and could it be that that's what you're really asking how to do? (ie: actually modify the base class at runtime to replace one of it's methods with a different function)

Comment: YES Exactly I think what I need, I'll search for that more and return back to u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, @BryanOakley's [now deleted] answer is the right one: if you want to use the features of the child class, instantiate the child class.

That being said, you can still access the parent's methods from the child. Let's say you have

```
class A:
    def start(self): return True
    def finish(self): return True


class B:
    def start(self): return False
    def finish(self): return False
```

If your reason for wanting to instantiate `A`, but use the `start` method of `B` is that you want the `finish` method of `A`, it is always much safer to call the methods of the parent on the child than vice versa:

```
b = B()
b.start()
A.finish(b)
```

This is a perfectly reasonable technique, and is used quite commonly. There is nothing inherently unsafe about it if you use it with moderate care.

Now, as it happens, Python uses duck typing. When you access a particular method or attribute, it will attempt to access that method or attribute directly, usually without checking the type of the object. This means that *technically*, and I really do not recommend this, you can do

```
a = A()
B.start(a)
a.finish()
```

If the `start` method of `B` does not access something that exists in the child but not in the parent, you can get away with this. But please don't, code has a tendency to change and something you "can get away with" now will usually come to bite you later.

**EDIT**

It sounds, after your edit, that you are asking about monkey patching perhaps. It appears that you actually want to replace the method `start` in an existing class with an alternative implementation that you defined elsewhere. This is not generally a good idea: it is much better to configure things properly up front whenever possible. That being said you can do something like this:

```
# Defined externally
class A:
    def start(self): return True

# Defined by you
def start(self): return False

A.start = start

a = A()
a.start()  # False
```

If you have only a single method in mind, you can replace it directly, as shown here. You do not need a whole class definition for that. You can monkey patch a class (or other attribute) at the module level using a very similar technique. The change will be visible throughout your code since all imported modules normally point to the same object. Monkey patching a method on an instance is also possible, but less trivial.

Comment: Look I edited the question, so what you said is too good but not In my case, It's my fault I have to put question in the right context.
Thanks btw, and if there's any advice related to my case.

Comment: @A.Raouf. Let me know if my update answers your question.

Comment: Your answer is working but not in my case too and I don't want to drive it to a django issue, as it is the package I use not designed well to do so, but whatever I'm very thankful for your care.

Comment: @A.Raouf. Unfortunately, I feel like your question lacks enough detail for me to be able to construct a better answer for you.

Comment: No no, I just ask about if it is possible or not but don't want to go deep to the problem at django project, @bran referred me to `monkeypatching` and I'll search if it is available or not

Comment: @A.Raouf. My edit shows you how to do it. Replacing an existing class method at runtime *is* monkeypatching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158021/discussion-between-a-raouf-and-mad-physicist).